# How would I approach this sort of transformation?

Tags: substitution

How would you substitute $u=$$\frac{mH}{k-m}$ into $v=(1-u)(u+H)$ to produce 
$v=\frac{kH}{(k-m)^2}(k-m(1+H))$?

Ideally I'd like  a step by step breakdown with the intuition described so I can learn how to approach *this kind* of question in the future over *this* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1-u= 1- \frac{mH}{k-m}$ & $u+H = \frac{mH}{k-m} +H$. Further simplifying,

$1-u= \frac{k-m(1+H)}{k-m}$ & $u+H = \frac{kH}{k-m}$. Multiply the two expressions, we're done!!